# Python script using robobrowser to submit a form on bitbucket to import repo

Tags: python, forms, bitbucket, robobrowser

I have some repos in my bitbucket user account and I want them to import to a team I created.

I looked in Bitbucket API references and couldn't find any API which can import a repo from my account to a Team.

So I am trying to write a script which can do the same. I am using [robobrowser](http://robobrowser.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) library.

I am able to fill up the sign in form, sign into my bitbucket. Then I fill up the form which sends a POST request to import.

After I fill up and submit, the response I am receiving back is same as old page which has the form. The response status is **200**, but I don't see new imported repos in my bitbucket team.

Here is my code which I am using to login into Bitbucket:

```
from robobrowser import RoboBrowser
browser = RoboBrowser()
url = 'https://bitbucket.org/account/signin/'
browser.open(url)
signin_form = browser.get_form(id='login-form')
signin_form['username'] = bb_username
signin_form['password'] = bb_password
browser.session.headers['Referer'] = url
# signin_form.serialize() 
browser.submit_form(signin_form)
```

and this is code which I am using to submit the import-repo form, which is failing:

```
url = 'https://bitbucket.org/repo/import'
browser.open(url)
import_form = browser.get_form(id='import-form')
import_form['source'] = 'source-git'
import_form['url'] = 'https://github.com/avinassh/talkwithme'
import_form['name'] = 'test-import-repo'
# import_form
browser.submit_form(import_form)
```

Any idea why this is happening? robobrowser is a very new library, is there any better library with good documentation for my task? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I use urllib to to scrap webpages which need authentication it is quite easy to use too

Comment: Looks like you got redirected back; look at `browser.state.response.history`. You could try setting a user agent so see if bitbucket will then accept the login.